# How to delete a folder and move its contents to the parent in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have many packs of icons downloaded from a website whose downloads are structured as: `pack/svg/icons`, but this redundant structure is not ideal for my project. I just want to have my icons directly under the pack directory. So this is how it is now:

```
 Categorized Icons
  └ RandomCat1
      └ svg
          └ icon1.svg
          └ icon2.svg
   └ RandomCat2
      └ svg
          └ moreicons.svg
          └ alldifferentnames.svg
```

And how I want it:

```
 Categorized Icons
  └ RandomCat
      └ icon1.svg
      └ icon2.svg
```

The problem is that I don't know RandomCat's name, and I don't want to run this command for every possible folder. I need something like, "move all icons to ../, delete /svg/".

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: What about possible duplicate file names when flattening a folder structure? BTW there *'are**  similar Q&A, use the search box above or google to find them.

Comment: Won't be duplicate names for the packs. Code so far: `Get-ChildItem -Path source -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination dest` but don't know what `dest` would be as it can't be `../` so I assume there is a better command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First enumerate all directories named "svg" under your base directory. The returned `DirectoryInfo` objects can be used for accessing the folder content. They also have a property `Parent` that references their parent folder object. Use the latter as the target for moving the former. Delete the source folder afterwards.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\folder' -Filter 'svg' -Directory -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item "$($_.FullName)\*.svg" -Destination $_.Parent.FullName
    Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
}
```

Note that in PowerShell versions prior to v3 `Get-ChildItem` doesn't have a parameter `-Directory`. If you're restricted to antiquated versions you need to use something like this for enumerating the "svg" folders:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\folder' -Filter 'svg' -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer
} | ...
```

Comment: Flawless, and way over my head. Thank you! And thanks for providing the second bit; my windows 7 computer couldn't run the first, but switching to my windows 10 and running the command helped. Always nice to have a fallback, though.

Comment: You can update your powershell version on your Windows 7 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616